# Do I need a visa for Malaysia?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, malaysia

I will be travelling to Vietnam from India (Indian citizen). I have a flight that has a 5-hour layover in Kuala Lumpur. I have to change terminals in KUL, and I'm not sure if I need to get a transit visa. I will land in T2 with AirAsia.

If I do need a transit visa or any other visa as an Indian, how do I get it?

Does the visa-free deal for Indian citizens from December 1 2023 to December 2024 help me get through to another terminal and catch my flight to Vietnam (Vietnam Airlines operating from T1 of KUL)?

Comment: No, scenarios are different , I will be directly travelling into Malaysia from India on an onward Journey to Vietnam.

Comment: I just want to understand if the visa free deal for Indians is a blanket approval for anyone travelling into Malaysia or if someone takes a connecting flight to another nation from another terminal need a different type of visa ?

Comment: [UPDATE from High Commission Chennai] As per the current order for Indian citizens travelling to Malaysia [VISA free from DEC 2023 - DEC 2024 ] there isn't any visa that could be issued.

Comment: We need to fill a form to get Malaysian Digital Card each time we enter Malaysia

Comment: @msk your scenario might be different but the same policy still applies. A layover is a layover, whether it's during the onward journey or during the return journey.